# adding an item in to React global state is not working?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add an item in to global state using the context API
and then render the item using map to pass id in to it any idea how to do it ?

[enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-sun-tutnl?file=/src/BoxContainer.jsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in the `appReducer`, take a look at this [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-cherry-g8wud?file=/src/context/app/appReducer.js)

Comment: dok its working i have issues with syntax so thanks